# Jquery problem in IE

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer

I am having jquery problems with IE 7. my code is **(in header.php)** -

```
<script type="text/javascript">
// <![CDATA[
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".jcl").jCarouselLite({
        btnNext: ".next",
        btnPrev: ".prev",
        visible: 1,
        auto: 2500,
        speed:1500
    });

    $('#nav2').nmcDropDown({
       submenu_selector: 'div',
       show: {opacity: 'show', top: '-=10px'},
       show_speed: 200,
       hide: {opacity: 'hide', top: '+=10px'},
       hide_speed: 400
    });
    $('ul#portfolio').innerfade({
        speed: 1000,
        timeout: 5000,
        type: 'sequence',
        containerheight: '340px'
    });
    <?php if($browser!='IE'){ ?>
    var images = $('.banner-image');
    var total = 12;
    var count = 0;

    $('#loadingGif').show();
    images.load(function() {
        count = count + 1;
        if (count >= total) {
            $('#loadingGif').hide();
        }
    });

    $(window).load(function() { $('#loadingGif').hide(); }); 
    //setTimeout(function() {$('#loadingGif').fadeOut('fast');},    20000);
    <?php } ?>
})
// ]]>
</script>
```

and in another page **(winning-photograph.php)** is -

```
<script type="text/javascript">
// <![CDATA[
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.lightbox').lightbox();
    $(".pic").hover(
      function () {
        $(this).css({border:"5px solid #FFFFFF", opacity:"1.0", filter:"alpha(opacity=100)"});
      }, 
      function () {
        $(this).css({border:"5px solid #999999", opacity:"0.6", filter:"alpha(opacity=60)"});
      }
    );
});
// ]]>
</script>
```

**hader.php** is included to **winning-photograph.php**. I do not any problem in other browser, but in IE. it is showing 2 JS errors -

1. **expected identifier, string or number**. (may be for header.php)
2. **object doesn't support this property or method**. (may be for winning-photograph.php)

I cannot figure out what to do. can anyone help? Here is the URL of my live site -

http://www.celebratinglifebd.com/winning-photograph.php?y=2010

Comment: Does the debugger give you line numbers so that you know which line it is throwing errors at?

Comment: If you install the IE script debugger, it'll take you to the exact spot where the error occurred. It may not be where the error-causing code was called from, but it's still far better than the default moronic error messages that flat-out lie to you

Comment: I'm not getting any errors here in IE?

Comment: The first thing I would do is run all of your JS code through jslint.com. I've found and fixed countless IE-related errors this way.

Comment: actually i am getting error in IE 7. so the lightbox is not working for the images in that page. when you just open the page, there is no error. then click one of the thumbnails in main contents; it will go to another page to open that image. then hit back button of browser, you will see error. it shows one error at line-18 and another at line-393. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I'll do some digging but I remember jQuery saying that binding events to the window `$(window)` can cause issues.